# &nbsp; in regex won't get removed

Tags: php, regex

and it's driving me nuts. I tried everything. I have two strings.

The first one `Allee 4`
The second one `&nbsp;4`

These are the regexxes I tried

```
$a = preg_replace ( "#\&nbsp\;#u", " ", $address[1]);
$a = preg_replace ( "#\&nbsp\;#", " ", $address[1]);
$a = preg_replace ( "#&nbsp;#u", " ", $address[1]);
$a = preg_replace ( "#&nbsp;#", " ", $address[1]);
```

None of them worked. The string always stayed `&nbsp;4`. Am I missing something?

Of course I already save the replacement into a variable...

Comment: `preg_replace` returns changed value. Are you not doing `$address[1] = preg_replace ( "#&nbsp;#", " ", $address[1]);`?

Comment: [Cannot confirm](http://regex101.com/r/mC8eE8)

Comment: Yes, I'm assigning it to a variable of course!

Comment: I think the search string should be &nbsp rather than the space character. Try using something like this preg_replace ( "#\&nbsp\;#u", "&nbsp", $address[1]);

Comment: Yes @h2ooooooo I'm also using regex101 and it works there, but not when I do it in PHP.

Comment: The problem is Alex, even when I replace it with X it doesn't work.

Comment: @Musterknabe: Can you do `var_dump( $address[1] );` at start and show its output here.

Comment: @Musterknabe [Still can't confirm](http://codepad.org/YKe4lsg7)

Comment: Ah, there seems to be the problem @anubhava

The output is `string(15) "Bilker AlleeÂ 4"`

Comment: Yup that's indeed the problem as there is no `&nbsp;` in your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this one a shot:

```
$address[1] = html_entity_decode($address[1]);
$address[1] = preg_replace("/\s/",'',$address[1]);
echo $address[1];
```

If it's working, do this to re-encode:

```
html_entities($address[1]);
```

Comment: That was the problem! Also, since the String I have was ISO Encoding I had to do

`            $business->address_street       = preg_replace("/\s/u",' ',$address[1]);`

Comment: Yeah, I've encountered that one before where php preprocesses the nbsp into \s ;) The encoding is a good catch too.

Answer (score 0):

preg_replace does not operate in place. It returns result so you must do:

```
$address[1] = preg_replace ( "#\&nbsp\;#u", " ", $address[1]);
$address[1] = preg_replace ( "#\&nbsp\;#", " ", $address[1]);
$address[1] = preg_replace ( "#&nbsp;#u", " ", $address[1]);
$address[1] = preg_replace ( "#&nbsp;#", " ", $address[1]);
```

Comment: @anubhava no I've not but know what you mean

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use:

```
$address[$i] = preg_replace("/&nbsp;/", "", $address[1]);
```

You need to delimit regexes with `//`. Not sure if `&` or `;` are escape characters, but I think not in this context.

Comment: You can also delimit with `#` or whatever you want. I tried both escaping and not escaping the `&` and `;`